# Sharing axes for generated subplots matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

OK, I've got myself thoroughly confused...
I have code that is generating a figure containing 8 sub-plots

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

names = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"]
x = np.arange(1,11)
y = x**2.
z = x**1.5

fig = plt.figure()

fig.text(0.5, 0.02, "X axis", ha='center', fontsize=12)
fig.text(0.03, 0.5, "Y axis", va='center', rotation='vertical', fontsize=12)
palette = plt.get_cmap('tab10')

for name in names:
    i = names.index(name)+1 # What sub-plot are we on?
    graph = fig.add_subplot(4, 2, i)
# Add a new subplot to go in the grid (4x2)
    graph.set_title(f"plot {name}", fontsize=11)
    plot = graph.plot(x, y, color=palette(1))
    plot = graph.plot(x, z, color=palette(0))


plt.subplots_adjust(
top=0.93,
bottom=0.116,
left=0.124,
right=0.977,
hspace=0.972,
wspace=0.165)


plt.show()
```

It works fine, except I can't work out how to set the sub-plots so that they share x and y axes (I only want axes on the bottom edge for the x axis and left hand edge). All the examples I've been able to find seem to rely on each subplot having a different name that you can use to set `sharex` or `sharey`. Since I'm generating them as I go, there is nothing for the code to point to.

Comment: Are any of the examples in the matplotlib gallery / examples section of any help to you?

Comment: "each subplot having a different name that you can use to set sharex or sharey. Since I'm generating them as I go, there is nothing for the code to point to". If you are referring to the fact that your `graph` variable is continuously overwritten: have you considered add each subplot to an array of `graph[]` (`graph.append(fig.add_subplot(...`)?

Comment: I couldn't find anything relevant in the matplotlib gallery (they are all built manually) and no, I hadn't considered adding graph to an array. So, now I feel stupid @00. Should I just delete the question?

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps not. I'd actually prefer if you self-answer it with your solution (so that we see how you use sharex/sharey). Perhaps just the important bit, that is, the for-loop. With an actual answer, it may be practical if other people run into the same issue (in fact, this may already be a duplicate question, but it may be harder to find an appropriate duplicate than (self) answering the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, here is a working answer

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 2, sharex='all', sharey='all')
graphs = axs.flatten()

for ax in graphs:
    ax.plot(x,y,color=palette(0))
    ax.plot(x,z,color= palette(1))
```

I've changed from the `fig.addplot` version above to a version which sets up all the sub-plots beforehand (`plt.subplots(y,x)`), and then just uses the loop to populate them.

Still don't seem to be able to remove the tick marks on the hidden axes labels though...